# node-datetime doesn't match with my local time

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

I use node-datetime as my package to get date & time, the problem is, when i wake up, the datetime is always changed in my server, so i need to restart my project first in the morning to get the real time. But if i save to my mysql database, it saves the real time.

```
module.exports = {
 'connection': {
   'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '',
    'timezone' : 'utc',
    'dateStrings' : true
},
'database': 'cash_hunter' 
};
```

that's my code, i've been finding the solution for many weeks

Comment: Where are you hosting your server?

Comment: i'm in indonesia, local vps provider

Comment: What does "real time" mean above? As in you want getting the time from your timezone, not the one your server is in, or the time itself on the server is incorrect?

Comment: so, when i wake up in the morning, the node-datetime shows wrong time, it shows 23:56, but when i restart the project it shows real time which actually what i need, the server time is right but node-datetime is wrong

Comment: Ill need to see where in your code you are using these times to be able to help

Comment: `var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
var dt = dateTime.create();
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d');
var time = dt.format('H:M');`